# Removing a HDD from a RAID 1 SATA HDD will it still work?

Tags: centos, raid, hardware-raid

I have a a Proliant ML 110 G5 server with an Embeded SATA controller running RAID 1 on two 160 GB drives. I had an issue with my CentOS Installation and after running e2fsck (via Ubuntu Pendrive) y booted into a system that was not recognizing my RAID 1 Array showing me both drives with different partition tables, not mounting two of the 6 Partitions on my HDD, and using only one of the HDD.

How would I go around removing one of the drives, removing the RAID 1 while still keeping the Data on the drive, and being able to boot my linux distro from it?

Appreciate any feedback,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Based on the use of the embedded controller, you should be able to just remove one of the drives.  I would also check the controller's firmware settings in order to disable the second drive if the setting is available at all.  We have several Proliant ML 110s here with RAID 1 pairs and they have continued to run even when one drive in the pair failed. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can certainly remove the RAID 1 drive, but don't forget to change the settings to normal for the proper drive functioning.
Though, I am not sure about the sync later, if you want to attach it again.